# Use of modal verbs devoir/pouvoir in "si + present" sentences

Tags: grammaire, conditionnel, futur

My attempt to translate

> If you are free on October 5, you should go.

is the following.

> Si tu es libre le 5 octobre, tu devrais y aller.

1. [This site](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/si-clauses-conditionals/) states that if the present tense is used in the "si" clause, then it should be followed by the present, future, or imperative. Is it ok to use "devrais" above, since the usage is as a ["modal verb"](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/modal-verbs/) rather than genuinely the conditional tense (which is typically used following "si + imparfait" clauses)?
2. Is it ok to use the present tense "si tu es libre" (like in English) instead of the future tense "si tu seras libre" even though the date is in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The conditional mood can be used; this is justified by the following remark in LBU § 1153 p.1515 (14th edition)

> Le verbe principal peut être au conditionnel, surtout au conditionnel atténuatif (§ 889,b, 1°) :
> ♦ J'AIMERAIS , si vous avez le temps, que vous passiez par la maison.
> — Il peut être aussi à l'impératif :
> ♦ Si vous revenez, REVENEZ la main tendue (COLETTE , Blé en herbe, IX).

2. The future cannot be used after "si".

> LBU § 1155 **b)** **Le temps** Il faut insister sur le fait que, parmi les temps de l'indicatif, le futur et le conditionnel sont exclus. ( Voir cependant § 1156.)
> Il s'agit de l'usage considéré comme correct. En effet, la langue populaire
> met assez souvent le conditionnel :
> ♦ Si vous m'AURIEZ ENNUYÉE, je vous l'aurais
> dit [dit une prostituée] (PROUST, Rech., 1.1, p. 373).
> ♦ Si je ne l'AURAIS pas EMPÊCHÉ, il venait voir comment qu'il est cousu, mon gant gauche [dit un boxeur] (COLETTE, Chéri, M. L. F., p. 42).

It is recommended to avoid the conditionnal: this type of popular grammar comes through as particularly awkward.

Yes, even though the date is in the future you have to use the present.

- S'il pleut demain, alors la récolte est sauvée. (<s>S'il pleuvra demain, …</s>)

Comment: '[It is recommended to avoid the conditionnal] [popular grammar]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer with quotes from LBU!